# How to redirect user to specific page after register in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, customer, register

I'm having a hard time with my custom module, I used the event **customer_register_success**.

Here's the part of my observer code. It will just give me an error 500. Just correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

/**
 * This is the extension to redirect into thank you page of account creation
 *
 */
class Register implements ObserverInterface 
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_url;

    public function __constrtuct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
     {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
        $this->_redirect->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **events.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="registerAfter" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RegisterAfter" />
    </event> 
</config>
```

**Create RegisterAfter.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/RegisterAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RegisterAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;

    protected $_redirect;

    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('thank-you-account-creation');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();           
    }
}
```

Note: Remove var/ or flush cache after adding observer

Comment: Hi @PrincePatel, Thanks I will try your code. I will comment back in here if it will work. Thanks

Comment: Hi Prince Patel, I tried your code. and cleared var and cache. but it will just give me a 500 server error. I've been researching the whole day but no luck. Thanks

Comment: @MazeStricks I tried your code and it's working perfectly in my system. Share your event xml.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="custom_redirect_register_success" instance="MazeStricks\CreateAccount\Observer\Register"/>
    </event>
</config>

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Prince Patel. I hope you can help me. Thanks again

Comment: @MazeStricks Check my updated answer. you made mistack in config. don't forget to remove var or flush cache after changes

Comment: Hi, @Prince Patel!! Thank you so much, bro!!!  your codes work great!!! I will accept this one as an answer to my question. your efforts are greatly appreciated. Thank you again

Comment: Although it's redirecting to my custom cms page. but after redirecting. after the account creation it will require me to login instead of automatically logged in as a customer after account creation. Thanks

Comment: @MazeStricks You can post other question for this to make better and clear Magento community.

Comment: Hello @Prince Patel, Ok I will post it. I'm currently at mobile phone. I will let you know once, I have posted it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor` for redirect from observer

```
public function __construct(
     ---------
    ResponseInterceptor $responseInterceptor
) {
    $this->responseInterceptor = $responseInterceptor;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    //your code
     $this->responseInterceptor->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Thanks for this one. I will try it also. I will give a feedback if this works. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Yogesh, I tried your code. It's good because somehow it will not give me an error 500 but it will not redirect me to my desired page. Instead, it will just show a message in create account form. but when I check on the backend of the site the customer is added.

Comment: try to change event from customer_register_success to customer_login